# Run a set of tests based on the Global boolean value

Tags: java, junit

I have the code for the tests provided below.

If the *isApi* is *true*, I would like to run the *testExecute*, otherwise, the *legacyTestExecute*. Basically, I have many tests can be grouped as A and B. So, I would like to run the group A tests for the *isApi* is *true* and the group B otherwise.

I can write if/ else kind of statements to handle this but is there any generic way to code this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JUnit5 there are annotations to enable/disable execution of tests depending on the value of a system property or environment variable:

```
@Test
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named="legacy.test", matches="(yes|true)")
public void testLegacy() {}

@Test
@DisabledIfSystemProperty(named="legacy.test", matches="(yes|true)")
public void testApi() {}
```

If you need to enable/disable the test based on the configuration property, you can provide custom condition:

- implement annotation

```
@Target({ METHOD, TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(EnabledIfPropertyCondition.class)
public @interface EnabledIfProperty {

    String named();

}
```

- extend `ExecutionCondition`:

```
class EnabledIfPropertyCondition implements ExecutionCondition {
 
    private static final ConditionEvaluationResult ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT =
            ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled(
                "@EnabledIfProperty is not present");
 
    @Override
    public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {
        AnnotatedElement element = context
            .getElement()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        return findAnnotation(element, EnabledIfProperty.class)
            .map(annotation -> disableIfPropertyNotSet(annotation, element))
            .orElse(ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT);
    }
 
    private ConditionEvaluationResult disableIfPropertyNotSet(
            EnabledIfProperty annotation, AnnotatedElement element) {
        String named = annotation.named();
        boolean usingApi = isUsingApi(named);
        if (usingApi)
            return enabled(format(
                "%s is enabled because %s property is set",
                element, named));
        else
            return disabled(format(
                "%s is disabled because %s property not set",
                element, named));
    }

    private boolean isUsingAPI(String propertyName) {
        
        String s = "src/test/resources/brink.properties";
        Resource r = new FileSystemResource(s);
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        
        try {
            props.load(r.getInputStream());
            return BooleanUtils.toBoolean(props.getProperty(propertyName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("We have an error for reading the access and location tokens for Brink web-service config", e);
        }
    } 
}
```